# I capture the same web page as string for many times, but the screenshort strings are not always the same

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Thanks for [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

I wrote a selenium test case  and  wanted to compare  a special page's  old image and new image.
Firstly, I captured the page image as string and stored it to a file.

```
String oldCapturedString = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
```

I didn't do any change for my web programs.
Then I run my selenium test case again  and captured a new image as string.

```
String newCapturedString = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
```

I found the oldCaptureString wasn't always the sample as newCapturedString,
but sometimes the two string were the same.

I want to know why the selenium captured strings are not always the same at different time, or I made some mistakes.

many thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the old and new screenshots (i.e. the images) to see if they are actually identical or not?

Comment: Because even a change of 1 pixel will make the strings different, the browser may be a slightly different size, the page may not have fully rendered, it may have rendered with a 1 px difference in colour shade, etc, etc.  Image comparisons are hard to do as there has to be fudge factor, it's very hard getting the level right.

Comment: Hello,  Mr.vincebowdren and Mr. Ardesco . I got the reason of it.  Thank you for your kindly reply and appreciate your helping me.

Comment: I have the same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096549/inconsistent-results-with-small-pixel-rendering-differences-for-the-same-seleniu).
Do you remember your reason, zhubd?